# Attribute is required but not set (Unable to create snapshot class for interface)

Tags: configuration, liferay, liferay-7

My Liferay 7 server was using `SomeModule` happily, until I deployed a new version of `SomeModule` which has an additional required field `favoriteColor`.

Now whenever I try to load the portlet Liferay says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create snapshot class for interface some.SomeModuleConfiguration
        at com.liferay.portal.configuration.metatype.bnd.util.ConfigurableUtil._createConfigurableSnapshot(ConfigurableUtil.java:77)
        at com.liferay.portal.configuration.metatype.bnd.util.ConfigurableUtil.createConfigurable(ConfigurableUtil.java:51)
        at some.SomeModule.activate(SomeModule.java:50)
...
aused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute is required but not set favoriteColor
        at aQute.bnd.annotation.metatype.Configurable$ConfigurableHandler.invoke(Configurable.java:75)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1220.favoriteColor(Unknown Source)
        at some.SomeModuleConfigurationSnapshot407.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

The configuration UI for `SomeModule` does not show anything about `favoriteColor`.

How to fix that, for instance by setting `favoriteColor` to its default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative path would be using a OSGi configuration file to set defaults and missing values. You can use those files as you do for those modules that come with liferay; e.g., elasticsearch config. (check your osgi/configs directory)

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough to have the source code of the module, you can solve this problem like this:

1. Temporarily make the new field optional, but replacing `required = true` to `required = false` in `SomeModuleConfiguration.java`.
2. Deploy the module.
3. Load the configuration page, save.
4. Restore to `required = true`.
5. Deploy again.

Alternative answers welcome!

Comment: reasons I hate liferay